# confused why substring index ouf of bounds for first letter of input after while loop checks input is all letters

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to make a pig latin program that:
1. if the input word starts with a consonant, put that consonant at the end of the word and add ay.
2. if the input word starts with a vowel, add ay to the end.

I'm using a while loop to check whether the input is all letters and to keep asking for input until it is. The program compiles with no errors but when I run it an exception keeps coming at the line after the while loop exits saying my index is out of bounds when I try to get the first letter of the word, it seems basic but I dont know why this exception is coming up

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rev 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String vow = "aeiou";
        String ques = "Enter word";
        String reply ="";
        int counter = 0;
        String newword = "";
        boolean isword = false;
        String let = "";

        while(isword)
        {
            System.out.println(ques);
            reply = input.nextLine();
            for (int i =0;i<reply.length();i++)
            {
                let=reply.substring(i,i+1);
                if (let.matches("[a-zA-Z]")) counter++;
            }
            if (counter==reply.length()) isword=true;
        }



        String first = reply.substring(0,1);
        if (!(vow.contains(first))) newword = reply.substring(1,reply.length())+first+"ay";

        else newword = reply+"way";
        System.out.print("New word is "+newword);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your boolean "isword" is set to false at the start, so it skips the while loop entirely. That means the string "reply" is an empty string with zero characters in it, so you can't call substring(0,1) on it. This would require your string "reply" to have at least one character in it. That's what is causing your index out of bounds error.

Change the boolean "isword" to true and you'll start your loop. Then change the if (counter==reply.length()) to change isword to false instead of true, and you'll break out of your while loop.

Comment: Thank you for spotting my errors kadima its the simple mistakes i miss when i get tired .

Comment: @Snifflecry13 Perfectly alright, it happens to all of us. Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You never enter the `while(isword)` loop, as isword is false.

Since `reply` is still an empty string, trying to get one character from a string with *zero* characters is causing your problem.

Just initialise boolean isword to `true` or use a do-while.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about a pig Latin translator as a student project, write it in an appropriate language.  You could do this in Korn shell in, like, ten lines of code.

while true
do
    print Enter word:
    read WORD
    if [[ $WORD == "^[aeiou]" ]]
    then
        print "${WORD}ay"
    else
        INITCONS=$(echo $WORD | sed 's/^(.).*/\1/')
        REMAINDER=$(echo $WORD | sed 's/^.//')
        print "${REMAINDER}${INITCONS}ay"
    fi
done

Comment: thanks for the tip bruce , this exercise was only a study tool for a java repeat exam coming up but i'll still look into it !